# How to use DictionaryList with Linq?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have an xml file looks like this:

```
<Accounts>
  <Account Id="1">
    <UserName>xxx@Hotmail.com</UserName>
    <Password>xxx</Password>
    <AddingDate>06 Mart 2015 Cuma</AddingDate>
    <AccountType>Hotmail</AccountType>
  </Account>
```

I am using a Dictionarylist to keep both username and password values. I display just usernames like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("UserAccounts.xml");
namePassDictionary = doc.Descendants("Account").ToDictionary(e => e.Element("UserName").Value, e => e.Element("Password").Value);

foreach (var v in namePassDictionary)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(v.Key);
}
```

So I need to get the relevant password values stored in this dictionary list once a user checked any username from the checkboxList. How can I get the relevant password value from DictionaryList once SelectedIndexChanged gets fired?

I am stuck here:

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 1)
    {
        username = namePassDictionary.Where(ex =>ex.Key.Equals(""));
        frmSendMail sendMail = new frmSendMail();
        sendMail.Show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 1)
    {
        password = namePassDictionary[ex.Key];
        frmSendMail sendMail = new frmSendMail();
        sendMail.Show();
    }
}
```